# Is there a simple way of getting selected text in browser?

Tags: browser, text

There is need of getting selected text from browser (Chrome, Firefox) and passing it to variable. What is the best way to do this? I am using Windows and Java SDK. Using default browser for current system.

Comment: Do you mean to develop an add-on for browsers to clip texts from a webpage?

Comment: Browser extension/add-on or standalone java program. I guess an extension written in JS will be the easiest way for Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

There is no enough information to answer your question.

Which programming language are you using?
Which platform? Windows? Android? Something else?

Do you run a browser inside an application you are working on?

What do you need to do with the collected text? Store it? Process it? Change it?

Answer (score 0):

HTML? use jQuery, get the id of the field ? not enough info, what programming language you using?

use jquery to get the val, sample like
$('#id').val()